# PHP input date via form and process it

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date

I have a problem, there are 3 textbox to input postdate, title and content. when i am process it to send in mysql database. Textbox postdate can not send to mysql database. Just title and content are sent.

I need your help to solve this mistake. Thanks for your help

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $postdate=date($_POST['postdate']);
    $title= htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $content=$_POST['content'];
    $sql=mysql_query("insert into national_news(postdate,title,content)values('$postdate','$title','$content')");
    header("Location: nasional_news.php");
}
```

Comment: Chances are the postdate submitted via form and the table schema for postdate aren't lining up. Can you post your table schema?

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes. Enjoy having your site/DB pwned...

Answer (score 1):

if the date is getting from user then why use `date()` function? try with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$postdate=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['postdate']));
$title= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['title']));
$content= mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['content']));
$sql=mysql_query("insert into national_news(postdate,title,content)values('$postdate','$title','$content')");

header("Location: nasional_news.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your user entering `postdate`? The line you have, `$postdate=date($_POST['postdate']);` will be useless unless the user actually enters something like `'F m Y'. Look up [php.net's date page](http://php.net/date)

You should just accept the `postdate` without running it through the `date()` function.

Comment: just format date can entered into textbox, string can not entered, show me the way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    print_r($_POST);//Checking $_POST array values.
```

first you have to check where all value post from previous page and then continue with your code.
if checked then ensurer that your 'postdate' column datatype is 'date' and use or die() every time with the query() to know about query execution status.

for current date time of India use

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
    $dt= $dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");//for India
```